# Excel: cannot remove advanced filter

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I added **Data**->**Sort&Filter**->**Advanced** filter to a cell that allows me to quickly choose a name from a range of names stored in another sheet some time ago.

Now I would like to remove the advanced filter. I enter something like `=A17` in the cell, and it copies value from the A17. However, when selected, the cell still shows the drop-down button (a small button with triangle on the right) next to the cell, and when I select from the drop-down, it replaces the `=A17` with the selected value from the list.

How can I get rid of the drop-down list, i.e. the advanced filter option for that cell?
From the toolbar **Data**->**Sort&Filter**->**Clear**  is disabled all the time.

This is Excel 2007.